# How do I debug Resharper 4.0 add-ins?

Tags: resharper

Ok, I love Resharper and its addins, but even the best of fanbois have to admit that its API documentation is suboptimal. I'd like to build an addin myself (based on the [Agent Johnson](http://code.google.com/p/agentjohnsonplugin/) plugin). Thankfully that plugin works in 4.0, so I can use it as a starting point for my own work.

My question: how do I run and debug the app? The resharper plugins are in the \v4.1\Bin\Plugins\ directory -- do I set my output directory to that folder, run it, then start another instance of Visual Studio? Or is there some other hack/workaround I should try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should debug devenv.exe and use command line to load plugins, see [here](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/Building,+running+and+debugging+plugin)